# Python The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, machine-learning

this is my code:

```py
class Morpion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
        self.scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

    def ai_player_joue(self,joueur,list_mvt_possible):
        list_mvt_possible_copy=copy.deepcopy(list_mvt_possible)

        for i in range (0,len(list_mvt_possible_copy)):
            list_mvt_possible_copy[i]=self.convert_plateau(np.array(list_mvt_possible_copy[i]).reshape(-1)).astype(np.float64)

        self.scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(list_mvt_possible_copy)
        X_test=self.scaler.transform(list_mvt_possible_copy)
        self.clf.fit(X_test,list_mvt_possible_copy)

        proba_success_mvt=self.clf.predict_proba(X_test)
        indice_mvt=0

        for i in range (0, len(proba_success_mvt)):
            if(proba_success_mvt[indice_mvt]<proba_success_mvt[i]):
                indice_mvt=i

        self.plateau=list_mvt_possible[indice_mvt]
```

When I start my script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "morpion.py", line 282, in <module>
    morpion.train_ai_jeu()
  File "morpion.py", line 86, in train_ai_jeu
    sauvegarde_plateaux, result = self.ai_jeu(i)
  File "morpion.py", line 55, in ai_jeu
    self.ai_player_joue(self.J2,list_mvt_possible)
  File "morpion.py", line 204, in ai_player_joue
    if(proba_success_mvt[indice_mvt]<proba_success_mvt[i]):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I try some solution found her and on the web, but nothing works.

Comment: it's telling you that `proba_success_mvt[indice_mvt]<proba_success_mvt[i]` returns an array so your if statement is ambiguous. do you care if all the values are `True`, or maybe just 1 or maybe `n`. be specific...

Comment: I checked everything unless it was an array.
Thank you so much for putting your finger on the error